# How can I prove the convergence/divergence of this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image: question]

I can plug in huge numbers and it seems to tend to 4, but I don't know how I can prove this.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: Can you read what you wrote.

Comment: Do you mean as sequence or as series?

Comment: @gimusi sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply everything out, the term of the highest power of $n$ in the numerator is $32n^5$.  The highest power term in the bottom is $8n^5.$  So if you multiply everything out, and divide the top and bottom by $n^5$ you'll have something like

$$\frac{32 + \mbox{ junk }}{8 + \mbox{ stuff }}$$

where junk and stuff all have powers of $n$ on the bottom and so go to zero.

That makes your limit $4$.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to do it now